# How does bind account work in subdomains in AD

Tags: active-directory, subdomain, trust-relationship, domains

We have a parent domain and multiple subdomains. We created a bind account under parent domain to read users and groups from all the subdomains. How does the account created under parent domain authenticate itself to the subdomains? Is it via kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

The other domains "trust" security principals that authenticate with the parent domain.

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/concepts-forest-trust

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I am facing an intermittent issue with an application where I am trying read users from sub domains. It works fine but intermittently it says invalid credentials. But same credentials works agains the DC server later as well. So wanted to understand what would be causing this. I had done packet capture at the application end and checked the credentials being sent as well and it is correct..